# Cast WCF e.result and Generic classes

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have entity class in my wcf service and a method will return `List<MainClass>`.

While consuming service in the silverlight application e.Result need to access the   ForthClass. How to cast the e.result ?

```
public class MainClass
{
    public List<SecondClass> SecondClassList { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public List<ThirdClass> ThirdClassList { get; set; }
}

public class ThirdClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

UI Service Call:

```
ServiceClient.getNameCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    ObservableCollection<ThirdClass> test = ((ThirdClass)e.Result[0].SecondClassList).ThirdClassList ;
};
```

Comment: Post client (service call) code, please.

Comment: Posted with service call, please check.

Comment: What is `ForthClass`? What have you tried? What error do you get?